# AngularJS: Injector modulerr error on skeleton application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a very basic AngularJS app, from which I am trying to resolve the below error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=HelloWorld&p1=Error…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463)

All the online references I have found lead to correcting improper use of `ng-app` in one way or another, however I find that my code is as close as vanilla and correct as it can possibly get.

So being that this is a basic issue and I cannot seem to find the solution for it, could anyone please enlighten me as to the obvious mistake?

JavaScript

```
var myApp = angular.module("HelloWorld", []);

myApp.controller("mainController", function($scope){
    console.log($scope);
});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" ng-app="HelloWorld">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Hello World with AngularJS!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="mainController">
        Hello world!
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to make this example in plunkr for example, don't forget to reference your script file, `script.js`.

Check [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/aBm3rvjG9snXsaEU4cPy?p=preview).

I added `<script src="script.js"></script>`. Without it I get the exact error you describe. Basically Angular can't find a corresponding module declaration for the `ng-app="HelloWorld"` application.

So don't forget to include your actual application JS, containing the `angular.module` part.

Comment: Epic fail moment reached, thanks for enlightening me

Comment: Don't worry, we all make mistakes like this sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error since you are using ng features before importing Angular and you are not importing the file where you initialize your app module.

Do as shown below:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en-us" ng-app="HelloWorld">

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Hello World with AngularJS!</title>
  </head>

  <body>
   <div ng-controller="mainController">
       Hello world!
   </div>

  </body>

 </html>
```

**App.js:**

```
var myApp = angular.module("HelloWorld", []);

myApp.controller("mainController", function($scope){
    console.log($scope);
});
```

I hope I've been helpful.